# Volatility of stocks

Tags: equities, portfolio-management, portfolio-selection

I want to build a theoretical Portfolio with markowitz optimization for a course in University. The task is to build a Portfolio with low risk. So i want to do a CPPI strategy. Now the stock part of the Portfolio should contain stocks with small volatility. My thought is, that companies with big revenues (e.g blue chip stocks) are less volatile than stocks from younger and smaller companies. Am I right with my assumption and is there empirical evidence?

Comment: why don't you calculate the volatilities and prove your own hypothesis? I thought that was the point of university; to learn.

Comment: That would take to much effort to get the data. I thought maybe there are already Research papers which found empirical evidence for this hypothesis to which I can refer to

Comment: you can just pull historic market data from your market data provider in bulk - in work I use IDC which is paid for and at home i use the free Quandl datasets - and run your favoured measure across the whole set really quickly. I use R and the sd() function (standard deviation) on the log returns and it runs very quickly.

Comment: I am actually alluding to the idea that identifying low volatility stocks may be part of the assignment...

Comment: Actually I am not really interested in the particular volatility of the different stocks, I just need to get a investment horizon, which is somewhat easy to handle (max. 50 stocks for the optimization). I thought of 7 different sectors (defence, bio-tec, financials, etc.) in 2 different regions (europe and US). But now I need to do a pre selection of the stocks in this sectors and I thought of taking the 3 biggest (in terms of revenue) stocks. Now my argument would be, that these stocks are less volatile than the smaller ones. But to proof this, I would need to do a big empirical study

Comment: and this would go way further than needed for this small Task. So I thought that some Researcher may have done it before and I can refer to his empirical findings

Comment: You could take a shortcut and compare volatility of a blue-chip index (Dow 30) to the volatility of a small cap index (Russell 2000) and determine whether your hypothesis holds water.  That is only 2 calculations and could be done in about 10 minutes...

Comment: downloading the market data and calculating the standard deviation for each instrument should take a few minutes. If you write a small program to run it you can use functions to reduce this further. Say writing the program takes an hour (I just wrote something similar in 30 mins) and choosing the stocks (the hard part) takes a couple of hours then the calculations should take about 10 - 15 mins. so call it 4 hours to do the whole study. You will need the sd to optimise the quantities for the portfolio anyway so in half a day you can calculate the data that you need.

Comment: (part 2) how long should the assignment take? less than 6 hours total I just calculated including your "big empirical study"?

Comment: I don't want to do a preselection of stocks which I would do with selecting the low volatile ones. The selection is done using optimization. Also from which stocks should I compute the volatility then? All from the sectors I chose? I think we talk past each other. What I want is something like https://www.bloomberg.com/view/articles/2017-10-03/why-small-cap-stocks-are-finally-rallying but in an empirical scientific paper where I could refer to why I choose the stocks considered in the portfolio. If they get in the portfolio that is another question where Mr. Markowitz has an answer

Comment: also the idea from amdopt is good but then I need to explain, what I have done and I have really limited "space" in my work (5-8 pages). So even half a page is way to big.That is also the main reason why I want to find a paper with empirical results and just make a footnote and say for example "for more information read e.g paper ..." or one sentence in brackets with (empirical results can be for example in paper ..."